# How do I stretch a html5 video to width:600 and height 200?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video-player

How do I stretch a html5 video to width:600 and height 200?

When I try, the navigation bar increases in size but the video stays small

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="600" height="200" controls>
  <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ke8HX/1/

Comment: Works for me. Using Chrome, by the way.

Comment: @epascarello — That says "proportionally", that wasn't specified as a requirement for this question and the approaches are different depending on if it is proportional or not.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ke8HX/6/ You video is ok. You just don't see it because of white background.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the width and height attributes on the source tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/ke8HX/8/

HTML

```
<video class="vid" controls=true>
  <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

CSS

```
.vid {}
.vid source { width:600px; height:200px;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This kinda works...I don't think you're going to be able to modify the actual player control bar with just CSS though.  It's not even showing up on my version of Chrome Developer tools as an HTML layer to modify.  But the video does re-adjust!

The CSS:

```
#vid, #vid source { width:600px !important; height:200px !important;}
```

The HTML:

```
<video id="vid" controls=true>
  <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ke8HX/29/)